# How do I obtain gtrendsR results for same-day comparisons?

Tags: r

I have multiple terms and would like to know how the terms compare to each other on the same day:

```
search_terms <- c("apple", "oranges")
gtrends(keyword = search_terms,
        geo = "US",
        time = "2022-03-01 2022-03-01",
        onlyInterest = TRUE) -> output_results
```

I am currently getting the error, `Error: Cannot parse the supplied time format.` I get results when I add a few more days. Is there a way to get around this so I can just get results for one particular day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gtrendsR/versions/1.3.5/topics/gtrends) you should have between two dates:

> "Y-m-d Y-m-d" Time span between two dates (ex.: "2010-01-01
> 2010-04-03")

So what you can do is take it a day later and filter the desired date later out. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(gtrendsR)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
search_terms <- c("apple", "oranges")
gtrends(keyword = search_terms,
        geo = "US",
        time = "2022-03-01 2022-03-03",
        onlyInterest = TRUE) -> output_results

output_results$interest_over_time %>%
  filter(date == ymd("2022-03-01"))
#>         date hits keyword geo                  time gprop category
#> 1 2022-03-01   96   apple  US 2022-03-01 2022-03-03   web        0
#> 2 2022-03-01    2 oranges  US 2022-03-01 2022-03-03   web        0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>